# how to pass a mysql row variable with a form

Tags: php, mysql

I have this page where it displays some info from a database
here is some code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {        echo "<tr>";     
echo "<td><form action='deleteitem.php' method='get'><input type='submit'></form>  </td>"; 
echo "<td><textarea name='description' cols='40' rows='8'>" . $row['some_info']"
                  }
```

I'm not sure how to pass the particular row's id to the action script so that an item can be deleted by the user if they want

Comment: I'm thinking I assign the name of the input to the $row['item_id'] would that work?

Comment: invisible input tag with name as row_id and value as $row['item_id']..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" />
```